# Combine template filter django

Tags: django, templates, filter

In my template, I use multiple filters as below :

```
story|force_escape|markdown|nlToBr
```

I use this flow of filter many times in my page and I would like to create a filter that use those three filters.
Is there a way to do eat easily or do I have to find the code of each filter and copy paste back to back in on single custom filter ?

Thank you very much !
Dorian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [create your own template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), that would do this whole process for you, by combining the output of each filter, inside a Python function:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import force_escape, breaklines

register = template.Library()

# Let's say those filters are also here, since they are not
# built-in Django filters... Otherwise import them
@register.filter
def markdown(content):
    pass

@register.filter
def story(content):
    pass

@register.filter
def markdown_escaped(content):
    return story(
         force_escape(markdown(linebreaks(content)))
    )
```

And then in your template, use:

```
{% load yourapp_extra %}
{{ 'my_markdown_string'|markdown_escaped }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Filters are just functions; you can call them inside your own filter.

```
from ... import ...

@register.filter
def combo(value):
    return force_escape(markdown(nlToBr(value)))
```